# Why is IQueryable used instead of IEnumerable with MEF catalogs?

Tags: mef, iqueryable

Why is it that the catalogs expose parts through IQueryable and not just IEnumerable. I've been thinking about it but I don't understand how (or if) they actually use any of the IQueryable services that interface provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it allows for implementations which don't have to scan all available parts (an O(N) operation) for each query.

To give a concrete example, consider the following query which might be similar to something that MEF does internally to find an export with the right contract:

```
var matches = catalog.Parts
    .Where(part => part.ExportDefinitions.Any(
        export => export.ContractName == "foo"));
```

The catalog implementation of `IQueryProvider` could recognize the resulting expression tree as "give me parts which export the contract 'foo'" and then retrieve them from a dictionary by using 'foo' as the key, an O(1) operation - instead of actually enumerating all parts and executing the lambda passed to `.Where`, as would be the case for an `IEnumerable`.

**edit**: my example above isn't really a good one because there already is a [GetExports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833628.aspx) method specifically for this case; it wouldn't be necessary to query the `Parts` property like that. Perhaps a better example would involve `export.Metadata`.

Comment: So through the implementation of an IQueryProvider it actually does that kind of optimization, neat.

Comment: @John: I don't know if MEF *actually* does this out of the box, only that the interface allows for such implementations. You can create your own catalogs by deriving from `ComposablePartCatalog`.